# access sql Distinct Replace

Tags: ms-access

I work with access data.

I want to do something like :

```
select Distinct Replace(colFullName, Name, '') from tableInfo
```

but distinct and replace not working.

how do it?

Comment: What data do you have in columns `colFullName` and `Name`? What do you actually get, and what are you expecting to get in your result set?

Comment: colFullName : "John Doe", Name: "John"

Comment: What are you actually receiving?

Comment: I dont understand your question. I want to do : "select Replace(colFullName, Name, '') from tableInfo", but with a distinct.

Comment: Now that you've explained what data you're working with, how does your questions SQL statement perform? In other words, what result set are you getting when executing that query? You ambiguously say "not working", which doesn't help us who are trying to help you. What's the error message or result set that comes from your query?

Comment: I must say that this isn't clear. What table and column contains the value you wish to change.? What table and column contains the values you wish to use for the replace and how are the two tables, if they are different, related?

Comment: As with all database questions, show us some sample inputs and the expected output.